# How to get the output of an XslCompiledTransform into an XmlReader?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xslt, xslcompiledtransform

I have an `XslCompiledTransform` object, and I want the output in an `XmlReader` object, as I need to pass it through a second stylesheet. I'm getting a bit confused - I can successfully transform some XML and read it using either a `StreamReader` or an `XmlDocument`, but when I try an `XmlReader`, I get nothing.

In the example below, `stylesheet` is my `XslCompiledTransform` object. The first two `Console.WriteLine` calls output the correct transformed XML, but the third call gives no XML. I'm guessing it might be that the `XmlTextReader` is expecting text, so maybe I need to wrap this in a StreamReader..? What am I doing wrong?

```
MemoryStream transformed = new MemoryStream();
stylesheet.Transform(input, args, transformed);
transformed.Position = 0;

StreamReader s = new StreamReader(transformed);
Console.WriteLine("s = " + s.ReadToEnd()); // writes XML
transformed.Position = 0;

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(transformed);
Console.WriteLine("doc = " + doc.OuterXml); // writes XML
transformed.Position = 0;

XmlReader reader = new XmlTextReader(transformed);
Console.WriteLine("reader = " + reader.ReadOuterXml()); // no XML written
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`XmlReader.ReadOuterXml`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.readouterxml.aspx) method reads the XML for the **current node**.  When you first create the reader, there is no current node, so `ReadOuterXml` will return nothing.

If you add the line:

```
reader.Read();
```

...before the `ReadOuterXml()` call, then it will work as you expect.

P.S. You should normally test the result of the `Read()` method to ensure that the reader actually has something to read.

Comment: Ok, that kinda works. The XML in question contains the standard prolog, a root node and one child node. After one Read() still nothing is printed. If I do 2 calls to Read() before printing, I get the XML without the prolog. Why's this then?

Comment: @Graham: I'm not sure what you mean by "prolog" - I assume you mean the declaration?  Technically that directive is not part of the document, it's a header, so I can see why it wouldn't print.  If you know the name of the root element then replace `Read()` with `ReadToFollowing("NameOfRootElement")`.